# ¿Cómo concatenar dos listas en c# con nodos?

Tags: c#

Dadas dos listas de productos (precio, nombre), unir la primera lista con la segunda, en una tercera lista.

```
LISTA 1 = [4,7,3]
LISTA 2 = [1,6]
LISTA 3 = [4,7,3,1,6]
```

Encontré un código igual a este ejercicio que está en `c++`, y, no sé como ponerlo en `c#`. Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería bastante

```
//Clase Producto
    class Product
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Units;
        public float Cost;
    }

//Clase Nodo Producto
    class ProductNode
    {
        public Product Product;
        public ProductNode Next;
    }

//Clase lista
 class ProductList
    {
        ProductNode Head;

        public void AddProduct (Product product)
        {
            ProductNode newPNode = new ProductNode();
            newPNode.Product = product;

            if (Head == null)
            {
                Head = newPNode;
            }
            else
            {
                ProductNode last = Head;
                while (last.Next != null)
                {
                    last = last.Next;
                }
                last.Next = newPNode;
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            ProductNode pr = Head;
            while (pr != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Product name: {pr.Product.Name} - Units: {pr.Product.Units} - Total Cost: {pr.Product.Cost}");
                pr = pr.Next;
            }

        }
    }

//Main
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            ProductList productList = new ProductList();

            Product p1 = new Product();
            p1.Name = "Banana";
            p1.Units = 20;
            p1.Cost = 3000;
            productList.AddProduct(p1);

            Product p2 = new Product();
            p2.Name = "Apple";
            p2.Units = 30;
            p2.Cost = 5000;
            productList.AddProduct(p2);

            productList.Print();

            Console.WriteLine("----- LIST #3 -----");

        }
    }
```

Comment: échale un ojo a la documentación del método `Union()` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0

Comment: El problema está en que no puedo usar código de lista, es lista simple enlazada con nodos. Le agradezco mucho por el aporte

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una manera de hacerlo, no exactamente tu enunciado pero lo he hecho de manera más genérica.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    class Product
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public double Price {get;set;}
        
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Producto: {0}; Precio: {1:0.00}", Name, Price );
        }
    }
    
    class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data;
        
        public Node<T> Next;
        
        public void AppendAtEnd( Node<T> Node )
        {
            _= Node.Data ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Node.Data));
            Node<T> aux = this;
            while (aux.Next != null)
                aux = aux.Next;
            
            aux.Next = Node;
        }
        
        public void AppendAtEnd( T Data )
        {
            _= Data ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Data));
            if (this.Data == null)
                this.Data = Data;
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Adicionando Producto: " + Data.ToString());
                Node<T> NewNode = new Node<T>();
                NewNode.Data = Data;
                AppendAtEnd( NewNode );
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    static void PrintList<T>(Node<T> List)
    {
        while ((List != null) && (List.Data != null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(List.Data.ToString());
            List = List.Next;
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---Listas originales:");
        Node<Product> List1 = new Node<Product>();
        List1.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Cuerno de Unicornio", Price = 1e16 } );
        List1.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Chaqueta", Price = 50.2 } );
        Console.WriteLine( "Lista 1");
        PrintList<Product>(List1);
        
        Node<Product> List2 = new Node<Product>();
        List2.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Leche evaporada", Price = 0.32 } );
        List2.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Arroz", Price = 0.53 } );
        List2.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Frijoles", Price = 0.83 } );
        Console.WriteLine( "Lista 2");
        PrintList<Product>(List2);
        
        Node<Product> List3 = new Node<Product>();
        List3.AppendAtEnd( new Product() { Name = "Agua", Price = 0.21 } );
        Console.WriteLine( "Lista 3");
        PrintList<Product>(List3);
        
        Console.WriteLine( "---Adicionando la lista 3 al final de la lista 1");
        Console.WriteLine( "   En este caso la lista resultante está en la lista 1");
        List1.AppendAtEnd(List3);
        PrintList<Product>(List1);
        
        Console.WriteLine( "---Adicionando la lista 1+3 al final de la lista 2");
        Console.WriteLine( "   En este caso la lista resultante está en la lista 2");
        List2.AppendAtEnd(List1);
        PrintList<Product>(List2);      
    }
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución es este:

> ---Listas originales:
>  Lista 1
>  Producto: Cuerno de Unicornio; Precio: 10000000000000000.00
>  Producto: Chaqueta; Precio:
> 50.20
>  Lista 2
>  Producto: Leche evaporada; Precio: 0.32
>  Producto: Arroz; Precio: 0.53
>  Producto: Frijoles; Precio:
> 0.83
>  Lista 3
>  Producto: Agua; Precio: 0.21
> ---Adicionando la lista 3 al final de la lista 1
>     En este caso la lista resultante está en la lista 1
>  Producto: Cuerno de
> Unicornio; Precio: 10000000000000000.00
>  Producto: Chaqueta;
> Precio: 50.20
>  Producto: Agua; Precio: 0.21
> ---Adicionando la lista 1+3 al final de la lista 2
>     En este caso la lista resultante está en la lista 2
>  Producto: Leche
> evaporada; Precio: 0.32
>  Producto: Arroz; Precio: 0.53
> Producto: Frijoles; Precio: 0.83
>  Producto: Cuerno de Unicornio;
> Precio: 10000000000000000.00
>  Producto: Chaqueta; Precio:
> 50.20
>  Producto: Agua; Precio: 0.21

Comment: se lo agradezco mucho